# MongoDB: Is second index useless?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

In MongoDb, I have an index `{a:1,b:1}`.
Is creating another index `{a:1}` useless as it is already covered by the other one?

My queries are following the patterns: `findOne({a:"...",b:"..."})` or `find({a:"..."})`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need to create another index `{a:1}`, because of [`prefixes`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/index-compound/#compound-index-prefix).

> Index prefixes are the beginning subsets of indexed fields. For example, consider the following compound index:
>
> ```
> { "item": 1, "location": 1, "stock": 1 }
> ```
>
> The index has the following index prefixes:
>
> ```
> { item: 1 }
> { item: 1, location: 1 }
> ```
>
> **For a compound index, MongoDB can use the index to support queries on the index prefixes.** As such, MongoDB can use the index for queries on the following fields:
>
> - the `item` field,
> - the `item` field and the `location` field,
> - the `item` field and the `location` field and the `stock` field.

And creating a compound index is more efficient <sup>[[1]](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/create-indexes-to-support-queries/#create-compound-indexes-to-support-several-different-queries)</sup>.
And MongoDB can use an intersection of either the entire index or the index prefix <sup>[[2]](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/index-intersection/#index-prefix-intersection)</sup>.

Answer (score 1):

Check out MongoDB docs [Create a compound index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/#create-a-compound-index).

The following operation creates an ascending index on the item and stock fields:

```
db.products.createIndex( { "item": 1, "stock": 1 } )
```

> In addition to supporting queries that match on all the index fields,
>   compound indexes can support queries that match on the prefix of the
>   index fields. **That is, the index supports queries on the `item` field as
>   well as both `item` and `stock` fields:**

```
db.products.find( { item: "Banana" } )
db.products.find( { item: "Banana", stock: { $gt: 5 } } )
```

For a compound index, MongoDB can use the index to support queries on the index prefixes.

By the way,if you create a compound index:

```
{ "item": 1, "location": 1, "stock": 1 }
```

MongoDB can use the index for queries on the following fields:

- the item field,
- the item field and the location field,
- the item field and the location field and the stock field.

But it would not be as efficient on `item` and `stock`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question but your link does. "The following index on a collection: { x: 1, y: 1, z: 1 } Can support queries that the following indexes support: { x: 1 }, { x: 1, y: 1 }"

Comment: @RainingChain Sorry for that,I updated my answer,hope this helps.